# Example that $[X,Y]$ is not complete

Tags: examples-counterexamples, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

Let $X,Y$ be complete smooth vector fields on, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$.

What would be an example that $[X,Y]$ is not complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[x^2\partial_y,y\partial_x]=x^2\partial_x-2xy\partial_y$. The outcome is incomplete say because it's tangent to the line $y=0$, where it becomes $x^2\partial_x$, whose flow is easy to compute and see that it's not complete. (I guess there are easier examples, but it's the best I could do :)